# How to find out what Capital Cost Allowance would apply to the condo I invested in?

Tags: taxes, canada, real-estate, capital-cost-allowance

In this [example to claim Capital Cost Allowance on the CRA website](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/rntl/cca-dpa/mch-eng.html), how did the person Gwen come up with an amount of 1200 for the first year?

I have a condo that I rent out. I claim my expenses against the rental income, and it seems I can claim this Capital Cost Allowance on top of my expenses. Sweet! But I cannot figure out what amount to claim.

Comment: what [class](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/rntl/cca-dpa/clsss-eng.html) is your building

Comment: Oh boy...it is a condo in dowontwon toronto...after going through the list, i could not figure out which class it belongs to.

Comment: You probably shouldn't do it anyway if you plan to sell.  Maybe just depreciate the fridge and stove etc.  Have you read [this?](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/t4036/t4036-e.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I realize that after expenses, if my rental income is actually resulting in a loss, then i cannot use CCA to increase the loss and reduce taxes.

Comment: Please note that the pronoun "I", the first person singular, must be capitalized. "i" is not acceptable English.

Comment: I hope you aware that claiming CCA yearly will increase your tax liability when you sell. See here for more info: http://business.financialpost.com/2014/01/07/tax-tips-for-investors-clearing-up-real-estate-confusion/

Answer (score 1):

The answer wasn't far from where you started. In the future, I suggest you check the *Related Topics* listed on such pages. They are, after all, related topics; i.e. perhaps and probably what you need to know next. [Witness](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/rntl/cca-dpa/mch-eng.html):

> **Related topics**
>
> - Column 5 - UCC after additions and dispositions
> - Column 6 - Adjustment for current-year additions
> - Example of CCA calculation
> - Line 9947 - Recaptured capital cost allowance
> - Line 9948 - Terminal loss
> - Ownership
> - **[Rental - classes of depreciable properties](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/rntl/cca-dpa/clsss-eng.html)**      **← Over here!**
> - Rental losses

... and then, from the page resulting from *that* link, you'll see a mention of land vs. buildings, etc. and then inquiring minds might also click on the various classes of properties to end up at the [Classes of depreciable property](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/tx/bsnss/tpcs/slprtnr/rprtng/cptl/dprcbl-eng.html) page, which should contain exactly the descriptions you'll need to determine what building class yours falls into.

Run it by your accountant, to be sure.